# Why there is memory increasing?

Tags: python, sqlite, nltk

I wrote the below python code. I haven't got any array or list that needs memory and I can't understand why there is memory overflow.

```
con = db.connect('SentiWords.db')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Words")
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE Words(word Text, type Text) ''')
infile = open("train_reviews.txt")
lines = infile.readlines()
stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
sentiment_words = dict()
counter =0
for line in lines:
  words = nltk.word_tokenize(line.decode("UTF-8"))
  words = [ w for w in words if w.lower() not in stopwords]
  for word in words:
    counter_sent = 0
    counter_obj = 0
    check = swn.senti_synsets(word)
    for i in range(0,len(check)):
        if check[i].pos_score() < check[i].obj_score() and    check[i].neg_score() < check[i].obj_score():
          counter_obj +=1
        else:
          counter_sent +=1
    if counter_obj < counter_sent:
        cur.execute('''SELECT type FROM Words WHERE word=? ''', [word])
        data=cur.fetchall() #extract frequency
        if len(data) == 0: #if there isn't any frequency
           cur.execute("INSERT INTO Words VALUES(?,?)", (word,"no-obj")) 
    if counter % 1000 == 0:
        con.commit()
        con.close()
        con = db.connect('SentiWords.db')
        cur = con.cursor()
    print counter
    counter +=1
con.commit()
con.close()
```

I want to find from reviews all words that have got a sentiment meaning. So I decide to use sentiwornet to compare all words from the reviews and keep the words that have got sentiment meaning in a database. Can you exlain me what goes wrong ?

Comment: Would you mind including the error message so we can help you better?

Comment: I haven't got error message because I have enough memory to keep all the data that I need but  I watch the task manager and there is memory increasing without reason! Thank you for your response

Comment: If I understood you correctly you aren't really experiencing an "overflow" as per definition. Python is a garbage collected language, hence the memory usage is not deterministically determinable. You are creating objects, which take space and the garbage collection may only run when it is pressed for space, hence leaving you with permanently increasing memory usage.

Comment: Yes you are right. It is not overflow. How can I delete these garbages? After running a loop, I think that arrays,variables etc are initialized again. So, why there are garbages?

Comment: How big is the input file?

Comment: You *have* got a list; it's called `lines`.

Comment: I am ok with the input file. When the for-loop starts, there is memory increasion and I can't understand why

Comment: What's `db`? Some database implementations cache everything in memory until they need to flush it to disk.

Comment: import sqlite3 ad db.  I know this, that's why after 1000 words I clean up the memory.

Answer (score 1):

You can *force* garbage collection;

```
import gc

gc.collect()
```

Put the `gc.collect` call somewhere at the end of your loop.

But *in general* you shouldn't bother *unless* your program is consuming all your memory. And even in that case it is generally better to use a different algorithm.

In any case you should *profile* your application first before trying to *optimize* it. You could try [memory profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler).